# Why is my existing object not saved when I set it to a property of another existing object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this situation:

```
var customer = unitOfWork.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1); // existing customer
var certificate = unitOfWork.Certificates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1); // existing certificate

certificate.Customer = customer;

unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

The result is that no update takes place. When I check the `ChangeTracker.Entities` I see that my certificate is set to the customer. But I also see that the `State` is `Unchanged`... How is this possible? I've give a variable a value (`certificate.Customer = customer;`) and no changes took place?

What am I missing here?

Comment: does certificate has a property `CustomerId`? Try setting this `certificate.CustomerId = customer.Id` and then call SaveChanges

Comment: No, it doesn't. We are working with navigation properties.

Comment: Is unitOfWork a DbContext or some custom type? With EF5 and a DbContext the scenario you describe should save the changes.

Comment: @Martijn you have a 1:n association between Customer and Certificate, so there should be a property to store the ForeignKey

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra It is a custom type. So I guess the probles lies in there?

Comment: @Jehof I don't see a foreign key property with an int as a type, only the navigation prop.

Comment: @Martijn what association is defined between customer and certificate?

Comment: @Martijn are you able to post the UnitOfWork type here?

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra, Jehof I've solved it using a different approach. Instead of digging my objects from the UoW, I set the list of customers using parameters. It's a workaround for now, but I need to take a closer look with my collegue. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add the updated certificate again to database. Just use SaveChanges() method after updating the data. And if you want to add the new record after updating it you have to clone entire certificate object.

Comment: I've tried calling SaveChanges() just after `certificate.Customer = customer` but this didn't work.